# Choosing correct Http method

Tags: rest, http, api-design

I have a student resource and a course resource, i need to write a controller and method to enroll and disenroll student. What is the right type of http method should i use for enroll and disenroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the right type of http method should i use for enroll and disenroll.

`Enroll` and `Disenroll` sound like you are expecting to change the representation of a resource (possibly more than one).  So you can immediately dismiss any of the [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) methods (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, and so on).

One good heuristic for designing a REST api is to model it like a web site.  So what would a web UI for enrolling students look like?  Probably a bunch of pages with forms, when the form is submitted, you change the resource.

We know the answer is forms, because links on web pages are implicitly linked to the safe GET method, which isn't a good choice for changing a resource.  Similarly, we know that the method of the form needs to be unsafe as well.  As the only unsafe method supported by HTML forms is [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3); and it turns out that is fine.

Another option would be to model your API on a remote authoring environment.  In this idiom, the client would load a representation of the resource into its editor, make changes, and then send the altered representation back to the server.  [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) is the simplest choice - sending the entire modified representation back to the server.  [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) is an acceptable alternative, if you would rather send just the edits to the server.

The point is to provide an interface to your domain that plays nicely with generic http components.  Caches and browsers can do the right thing with representations without needing to understand the specifics of your messages.